# Using several Authenticators from same type in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'd like to use 2 simple_preauth Authenticators, one should be a fallback. That works when using several Authenticators of different type:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-customize-the-security-features-with-ease#using-several-authenticators-in-a-firewall

Also supportsToken() is implemented for that purpose: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#supportstoken

Am I missing something or what's the recommended way to add 2 simple_preauth Authenticators to a firewall where the 2nd is the fallback of the 1st? Or is it only possible if I implement one of them as custom Authenticator (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not miss something - you can define an only 1 `simple_preauth` authenticator per a firewall.

But you have the fallback option for the authenticator: if the authenticator implements `AuthenticationFailureInterface` then on `AuthenticationException` will be called its `onAuthenticationFailure` method.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#handling-authentication-failure
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/SimplePreAuthenticationListener.php#L94

Also you are free to try several authentication ways into `authenticator::createToken()`. Just don't forget to differentiate them into `authenticator::authenticateToken()` and `authenticateToken::refreshToken()` (if `stateless: false`).

You are able to extend `simple_preauth` behavior with Custom Authentication Provider but this is most complicated way. It can be several Custom Authentication Providers with overrided `SimplePreAuthenticationFactory` key and services suffices. Or it can be truly multiple `simple_preauth` implements Chain pattern for its Listener and Provider. e.g.

```
class MultipleSimplePreAuthenticationListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    ...
    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $listener) {
            $listener->handle($event)
        }
        ...
```

Comment: The simplest way was to integrate both into one authenticator, thanks!